# KDE somehow mute Konsole, yet IntelliJ terminal plays "beep" sound as normal

Tags: arch-linux, kde, konsole, bell

I found out that the "beep" sound is only produced inside of the IntelliJ's (RubyMine to be more specific) terminal. All `tput bel`, `echo ^G` and `echo $'\a'` produces a normal annoying sound. On addition it is played as normal if i use backspace when line is empty, or for example an right arrow when i reach the end of the text.
But when i run Konsole app (or Yakuake) it is completely mute.
I have the **"Play sound"** option for **"Bell in Focused Session"** event checked, in my Konsole > Settings > Configure Notifications (pic rel).
The play button, visible on the screen below, doesn't produce any sound neither.

[image: Configure Notifications - System Settings Module]

This produces a sound:
[image: tput bel used inside of IntelliJ terminal]
This does not:
[image: tput bel used inside Konsole]

Comment: File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal, uncheck Audible bell https://askubuntu.com/questions/994850/how-to-remove-error-sound-from-pycharm-terminal

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunately, I just realized, that I did not precise my question properly. My goal is NOT to disable bell in IntelliJ, my goal is to ENABLE bell sound in Konsole. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

In KDE `System Settings` app in `Accesebility` section turn off flag: `Use system bell`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Vitas's method did not work in my configurarion (Kubuntu 20.04). After enabling the sound file in Konsole Notifications settings, I right-clicked the sound icon in systray, `Configure Audio Volume`, `Audio`. In the `Applications` tab, the Notification Sounds slider was at zero. I put it at 100%; now, the notification sounds are audible.

[image: Audio Volume Settings window]

Comment: Thank you for your contribution!
I've resolved this issue by reinstalling OS.
Now configuration described in this topic works perfectly fine.